# Can not enable "Continuously Updates Value" in NSTextView attributedString binding

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

In Xcode 3 Interface Builder, when I check "Continuously Updates Value" in NSTextView attributedString binding, the checkbox is automatically unchecked.

Can "Continuously Updates Value" be enabled ? If so, what may cause this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem.

I deleted the NSTextView and created a new one. Now I could enable the "Continuously Updates Value"